# Using ActiveModel::Dirty in Rails Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I'm trying to use Rails ActiveModel::Dirty in my Model validations to require the presence of certain fields depending on what the `status` of my record was or will be.

**Current Validations**

```
validates :pause_reason, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |o| o.status_will_change! == "Paused" }
validates :unpause_reason, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |o| o.status_was == "Paused"  }
```

So the `pause_reason` validation seems to work fine, as in when I change the status to `Paused` and leave `pause_reason` blank I get the appropriate error "Pause Reason cannot be blank" likewise if I fill in said field I do not get the error.

However, when I try to save the same changes, the `unpause_reason` validation also presents the error "Unpause reason cannot be blank". I've tried to step through the steps in rails console with the following results:

```
irb(main):026:0> o.status
=> "Open"
irb(main):027:0> o.status = "Paused"
=> "Paused"
irb(main):028:0> o.status_will_change!
=> nil ## should be "Paused" I think
irb(main):029:0> o.status_was
=> "Open"
irb(main):030:0> o.status_was == "Paused"
=> false
irb(main):031:0> o.pause_reason
=> nil
irb(main):032:0> o.valid?
=> true ## should be false
```

So I guess I'm a little confused as to whats happening in the validation process that would cause the `pause_reason` validation to (seemingly) work as intended, but also failing the `unpause_reason` validation when the console clearly shows that the `status_was` equaled `"Open"`.

If someone could help me understand how to use ActiveModel::Dirty within Rails Validations appropriately it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Upon more research I decided to combine my 'status validations' into a single method that validates on `update` as follows:

`validates :status_change_validations, on: :update`

```
def status_change_validations
  if status == "Paused" && pause_reason.blank?
    errors.add(:pause_reason, 'required when pausing an order.')
  elsif status != "Paused" && status_was == "Paused" && unpause_reason.blank?
    errors.add(:unpause_reason, 'required when resuming an order.')
  elsif status == "Canceled" && cancellation_reason.blank?
    errors.add(:cancellation_reason, 'required when canceling an order.')
  elsif status != "Canceled" && status_was == "Canceled" && reopen_reason.blank?
    errors.add(:reopen_reason, 'required when reopening an order.')
  elsif status == "Reactivate" && reactivation_reason.blank?
    errors.add(:reactivation_reason, 'required when reactivating an order.')
  end
end
```

This seems to do exactly as I'm intending, although, I'm still not sure why the original single line validations with the `Procs` do not work. If someone still would like to explain that with a working answer to deepen my understanding of procs and validations or provide a better approach than what I've just listed I will accept your answer. But this works for now so I'm going to roll with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of method `[attribute]_will_change!` is not to present what attribute is going to be, but to mark an attribute of the object of a class which includes the `ActiveModel::Dirty`(in your case, a rails model class) that

> This attribute is going to change, please record the change in the `changes` attribute
>   ([ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html))

After sending the `[attr]_will_change!` to the object, the `[attr]_was` or `object.changes` or other methods of `ActiveModel::Dirty` can respond correctly.

So the wrap up of your question, there's nothing wrong with the `proc` there, but the way you use `[attr]_will_change!`. If I get it right, what you wanna do should be like this:

```
validates :pause_reason, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |o| o.status == "Paused" }
validates :unpause_reason, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |o| o.status_was == "Paused"  }
```